# Google maps utility library IconGenerator setColor not working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, icons

I'm using the Google maps utility library to generate an icon for my markers, and the setColor is not working, every color I set, is a different shade of blue, it's not my color, and it's also got a black stroke around, which I don't want.

this is the code:

```
for (place in location.locations) {
                    val locationPoz = LatLng(place.lat, place.long)
                    boundsBuilder.include(locationPoz)

                    //Here is the icon part
                    val icon = IconGenerator(requireContext())
                    icon.setColor(R.color.red)
                    val fIcon = icon.makeIcon("${place.price}€")

                    val marker = MarkerOptions()
                        .position(locationPoz)
                        .title(place.name)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(fIcon))
                        .alpha(5f)

                    googleMap.addMarker(marker)
                }
```

And this is how my map looks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only use one of the provided values in https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html

Try

~`icon.setColor(IconGenerator.STYLE_RED)`~

EDIT: I misread, I think. The STYLE_* values would have to be used like
`icon.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_RED)`

That doesn't yet solve your problem of the border you don't want, so instead, you would need to provide your own background drawable with `setBackground`

Comment: im gonna look into it thanks,until then,can you take a look at my new question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70217185/google-maps-utility-library-markers-not-clustering